# How to sum values based on filter and group by Year-Month

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-queryset, django-orm

I have the following table:

```
2018-01-01 ------- 10
2018-01-15 ------- 20
2018-01-31 ------- 30
2018-02-01 ------- 10
2018-03-01 ------- 10
2018-03-20 ------- 20
```

I need to Sum the values filtering it with

1 - sum(values) where date < the first day of the month

2 - sum(values) where date < last day of the month

Expected result(something like that):

```
[
 {'year-month': '2018-01'}, {'sum_before_month_day_one': 0}, {'sum_before_last_month_day': 60},
 {'year-month': '2018-02'}, {'sum_before_month_day_one': 60}, {'sum_before_last_month_day': 70},
 {'year-month': '2018-03'}, {'sum_before_month_day_one': 70}, {'sum_before_last_month_day': 100},
]
```

I found this on docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/aggregation/#filtering-on-annotations

But, I don't know to provide args to Q based by own query annotation.

So far I manage to sum values and group by month:

```
In [12]: result = Sale.objects \
    ...:     .annotate(date=TruncMonth('event_date')) \
    ...:     .values('date') \
    ...:     .annotate(quantity=Sum('quantity')) \
    ...:     .values('date', 'quantity') \
    ...:     .order_by('date')

In [13]: for i in result: print(i)

{'date': datetime.date(2018, 1, 1), 'quantity': 60.0}
{'date': datetime.date(2018, 2, 1), 'quantity': 10.0}
{'date': datetime.date(2018, 3, 1), 'quantity': 30.0}
```